# Problem with connecting on local SQL Server with EF Core 7

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I have simple web application, it is generated from Visual Studio on version .NET 5 and EF Core 5, and only thing added is WebDbContext and sql query to see if database connection works.

WebDbContext:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public class WebDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = SamuraiApp; Integrated Security = True;"; 
                                                                                                                          //Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyWorldDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine,
                        new[] {
                            DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name,
                        }
                        , LogLevel.Information
                        )
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }
    }
}
```

Get API:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {

            WebDbContext dbContext = new WebDbContext();
            var res = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE battles SET Name = Name");

            Console.WriteLine("Number of rows: " + res);

            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

This app works and it connects on database when you are using .net 5 and EF Core 5, if you are using .net 6 and EF Core 6 it still works, if you are using .net 7 and EF Core 6 it works but if you use .net 7 and EF Core 7 it cannot connect to database.

It shows error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)'
```

I haven't change something in code when I changed versions. I have database on this location and it works on older version of EF Core, but it doesn't work EF Core 7. Is something changed in EF Core 7 about connecting to server, which is on local machine and it has allias local?

Comment: If the solution not works for you, pls let me know.

Comment: [Breaking changes in EF Core 7.0 (EF7)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true)

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, I have updated the answer, and I think the issue may not related to the topic in the doc you shared. Pls follow the link in my answer and set it, thanks

Comment: Any updates ? The solution should useful to you. If u need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE

I double check the error message, there are another reason may cause the issue. Pls check the link to configure it. We don't need ApexSQL tools, just follow the doc to configure sql server.

[How to configure remote access and connect to a remote SQL Server instance with ApexSQL tools](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)

---

#### PREVIOUS

According the error message, you could follow my steps to get the correct connection string.

**The correct format should be like below:**

```
Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-Core6MVCSignalR-64406da8-b697-43cb-9c46-aaa950b705b1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

#### Steps

1. Open the sql server object explorer in the vs2022 (or other version)

   [image]
2. Find the DB (SamuraiApp)

   [image]
3. Find the connection string.

   [image]

Comment: The issue is not in an ill-formatted connection string otherwise it wouldn't work in lower EF versions.

Comment: @GertArnold Ok， as I mentioned, the error message point this, could you spend some time to test it.

Comment: @GertArnold Pls check it, it might help us to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, I double the issue, pls follow the link in updated answer to allow your sql server remote access. At first time I haven't found the sql express connectionstring, so I think it's related to the wrong connnectionstring issue.

Answer (score 0):

please install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer in nuget package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).